# Running expo prebuild -p ios --clean gives config sync failed

Tags: ios, react-native, expo

I am trying to make a iOS local build for my app so I could push it to expo dev for stores approval but I am getting error that I can't seem to debug and I'm not sure to what it's connected.

Is it connected to some dependency's version mismatching, being outdated or maybe with my app.config.js?

This is what I get:

```
✔ Installed JavaScript dependencies 18383ms
✖ Config sync failed
[ios.dangerous]: withIosDangerousBaseMod: url.startsWith is not a function
TypeError: [ios.dangerous]: withIosDangerousBaseMod: url.startsWith is not a function
    at Object.downloadOrUseCachedImage (/opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/@expo/image-utils/src/Download.ts:21:11)
    at ensureImageOptionsAsync (/opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/@expo/image-utils/src/Image.ts:120:25)
    at generateImageAsync (/opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/@expo/image-utils/src/Image.ts:148:22)
    at setIconsAsync (/opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/@expo/prebuild-config/src/plugins/icons/withIosIcons.ts:130:36)
    at /opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/@expo/prebuild-config/src/plugins/icons/withIosIcons.ts:15:7
    at action (/opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/@expo/config-plugins/src/plugins/withMod.ts:227:23)
    at interceptingMod (/opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/@expo/config-plugins/src/plugins/withMod.ts:108:21)
    at action (/opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/@expo/config-plugins/src/plugins/createBaseMod.ts:82:21)
    at interceptingMod (/opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/@expo/config-plugins/src/plugins/withMod.ts:108:21)
    at evalModsAsync (/opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/@expo/config-plugins/src/plugins/mod-compiler.ts:172:25)
```

This is what my app.config.js looks like:

```
export default ({ config }) => ({
  ...config,
  name: "NAME",
  slug: "MY-SLUG",
  owner: "filipvlaisavljevic",
  version: "1.0.0",
  orientation: "portrait",
  runtimeVersion: {
    policy: "appVersion",
  },
  splash: {
    image: "./assets/images/splashlogo.png",
    resizeMode: "contain",
    backgroundColor: "#FDEAE2",
  },
  web: {
    favicon: "./assets/logo.png",
  },
  android: {
    package: "MY-DOMAIN",
    icon: "./assets/images/logo.png",
    versionCode: 1,
    adaptiveIcon: {
      foregroundImage: "./assets/images/splashlogo.png",
      backgroundColor: "#FDEAE2",
    },
  },
  ios: {
    supportsTablet: true,
    bundleIdentifier: "MY-DOMAIN",
    icon: {
      iconSize: 120,
      ios: "./assets/images/logo.png",
      "ios/ipad": "./assets/images/logo.png",
      "ios/ipad_2x": "./assets/images/logo.png",
      "ios/ipad_pro": "./assets/images/logo.png",
      "ios/ipad_pro_2x": "./assets/images/logo.png",
    },
  },
  extra: {
    storybookEnabled: process.env.STORYBOOK_ENABLED,
    eas: {
      projectId: "DELETED",
    },
  },
});
```

Build was expected to be run but I am getting unknown error